# Neo4j cypher query language - order of operations for boolean expressions

Tags: neo4j, cypher, boolean-logic, boolean-operations

I am trying to write a query to pull data from my Neo4J database. Lets say there are five conditions that determine whether or not I want to pull _____ from my database: A, B, C, D, and E. The boolean expression which determines this is:

```
A && B && (C || D || E)
```

From scouring the web, I cannot find any information about an order of operations that Neo4J AND and OR queries abide by (AND usually precedes OR), but from my observations they seem like they execute sequentially. Since there is no way that I know of to explicitly define order, aka using parenthesis, how would one implement a Cypher query to satisfy the boolean expression above?

Answer (score 5):

> there is no way that I know of to explicitly define order, aka using parenthesis

Don't be so sure. ;)

First of all, there's *always* an association or grouping, even if it is implicit in case they are executed sequentially. Let's look at a case where this matters.

```
MATCH (n) RETURN CASE WHEN false AND true OR true THEN 'and' ELSE 'or' END
```

(This will work as long as there is at least one node in your database.)

This *must* be equivalent either to `((false and true) or true)` or `(false and (true or true))`, but these have different outcomes.

```
(false and true) or true => false or true => true
false and (true or true) => false and true => false
```

The query above will return "and" in the first case and "or" in the second, to show you which was executed first. It returns "and", because they are grouped sequentially.

```
MATCH (n) RETURN CASE WHEN ((false AND true) OR true) THEN 'and' ELSE 'or' END
```

This also returns "and", because this is the implied grouping you get when you execute the boolean operators sequentially.

```
MATCH (n) RETURN CASE WHEN (false AND (true OR true)) THEN 'and' ELSE 'or' END
```

But this returns "or".

That was a really long-winded way to say that adding parentheses is indeed the answer.

---

Just for fun, I tried to determine precedence, and it appears that Neo does have and-precedence:

```
MATCH (n) RETURN CASE WHEN true or true and false THEN 'and' ELSE 'or' END
```

If the or is grouped first:

```
(true or true) and false => true and false => false
```

If the and is grouped first:

```
true or (true and false) => true or false => true
```

The query above returns 'and', indicating the implicitly grouped construct evaluated to true overall (thus and was grouped first despite appearing last sequentially).

Comment: This is a complicated answer to a simple question. Why not paste a table for the order of precedence?

Comment: Because, as the question implies, it was not easily discoverable at the time. If one is available now, feel free to find and post it.

Comment: I looked again just now and there is a truth table but no precendence table [in the docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/operators/#query-operators-boolean). The word precedence does not occur in that page. Since it's not explicitly provided, but must exist even accidentally as a consequence of the implementation, you have to work out what the precedence is, as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

The [openCypher](https://opencypher.org/resources/) project defines a [grammar](https://s3.amazonaws.com/artifacts.opencypher.org/M18/grammar-M18.zip) for Cypher. This grammar indicates that order of precedence (from highest to lowest) of operators in Cypher would be:

- `IN`, `STARTS WITH`, `ENDS WITH`, `CONTAINS`, `=~`, `IS NULL`, `IS NOT NULL`: binary list and string matching along with null checking
- `+`, `-`: unary identity and negation
- `^`: binary power
- `*`, `/`, `%`: binary multiplication and division
- `+`, `-`: binary operations addition, concatenation, and subtraction
- `=`, `<>`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`: binary comparison operators
- `NOT`: unary logical NOT
- `AND`: binary logical AND
- `XOR`: binary logical XOR
- `OR`: binary logical OR