# Neo4j Cypher query: Parenthesis not considered in WHERE clause?

Tags: neo4j, nosql, cypher, graph-databases

I am trying to run a query like:

```
MATCH (n:Type1)-[:relation1]->(:Type1)<-[:relation2]-(:Type2) WHERE
((n.prop1="A" and n.prop2 in [42, 34]) OR
 (n.prop1="B" and n.prop2 in [67])     OR
 (n.prop1="C" and n.prop2 in [51, 43]) OR
 (n.prop1="D" and n.prop2 in [56, 42])) 
RETURN DISTINCT id(n) as node_id, n.prop3 as node_prop3, n.prop1 as prop1, n.prop2 as prop2;
```

This is giving mixed results ie `prop1="D"` matched with `prop2=51` which is clearly not in the intended condition. It is as if the parentheses have no say in the formation of conditional.
The results are the same when I run the query w/o parentheses in the WHERE clause.

Although, If I query something like:

```
MATCH (n:Type1)-[:relation1]->(:Type1)<-[:relation2]-(:Type2) WHERE
((n.prop1="A" and n.prop2=42) OR
 (n.prop1="A" and n.prop2=34) OR
 (n.prop1="B" and n.prop2=67) OR
 (n.prop1="C" and n.prop2=51) OR
 (n.prop1="C" and n.prop2=43) OR
 (n.prop1="D" and n.prop2=56) OR
 (n.prop1="D" and n.prop2=42)) 
RETURN DISTINCT id(n) as node_id, n.prop3 as node_prop3, n.prop1 as prop1, n.prop2 as prop2;
```

Is there something I'm missing when replacing the separate conditions in example 2 with the `IN` in example 1 to avoid repeated string comparisons for `prop1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that `IN` works as you expect.

Set up sample data.

```
(:Type1 {prop1:"A", prop2:34}),
(:Type1 {prop1:"B", prop2:67}),
(:Type1 {prop1:"C", prop2:51}),
(:Type1 {prop1:"C", prop2:43}),
(:Type1 {prop1:"D", prop2:56}),
(:Type1 {prop1:"D", prop2:42}),
(:Type1 {prop1:"D", prop2:51}),
(:Type1 {prop1:"B", prop2:42});

MATCH (t:Type1)
MERGE (t)-[:relation1]->(:Type1)<-[:relation2]-(:Type2);
```

Now run your query.

```
MATCH (n:Type1)-[:relation1]->(:Type1)<-[:relation2]-(:Type2) WHERE
((n.prop1="A" and n.prop2 in [42, 34]) OR
 (n.prop1="B" and n.prop2 in [67])     OR
 (n.prop1="C" and n.prop2 in [51, 43]) OR
 (n.prop1="D" and n.prop2 in [56, 42])) 
RETURN DISTINCT id(n) as node_id, n.prop3 as node_prop3, n.prop1 as prop1, n.prop2 as prop2;
```

The statement returns seven records, and the results do not include the node with prop1 = D and prop2 = 51.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239723/neo4j-cypher-query-language-order-of-operations-for-boolean-expressions) for information on the precedence of Boolean operators if you leave out parenthesis.

Comment: It does return [D, 51].
Please find the results I get [here](https://imgur.com/a/7aDJqXo).

Comment: Turns out it was an error in the neo4j image I was using (3.4.1). When I pulled the latest one (3.5.14), it was giving the correct results.

Thanks for the suggestion, I will mark your comment as the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm glad it's working for you!